# How can I get my JS function to overlook ID CSS and only look at Class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below code works fine:

```js
 filterSelection("all")
    function filterSelection(c) {
      var x, i;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
      if (c == "all") c = "";
      // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
      }
    }
    
    function w3AddClass(element, name) {
      var i, arr1, arr2;
      arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
      arr2 = name.split(" ");
      for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
          element.className += " " + arr2[i];
        }
      }
    }
    
    function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
      var i, arr1, arr2;
      arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
      arr2 = name.split(" ");
      for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
          arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1); 
        }
      }
      element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }
    
    var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
    var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      });
    }
```

```css
 .container {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .filterDiv {
      float: left;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      color: #ffffff;
      width: 100px;
      line-height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2px;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .show {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .btn {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .btn.active {
      background-color: #666;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="myBtnContainer">
      <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
      <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
      <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
      <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
    </div>
```

But if I change one of the divs from e.g.

```
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
```

to

```
 <div class="filterDiv animals" id="othercss_unrelated_to_function" >Dog</div>
```

It completely breaks the function. How can I get it to prioritise the class CSS?

I would like to have the function work around the ID CSS. Is there a method of ordering them into a hierarchy so they don't interfere with my JavaScript?

Comment: Try to look first at your js console and check for any error.

Comment: Thank you. There are no errors shown, but the conflicting CSS stops the function from working.

Comment: @ohbrother I've tried your code, and it's working just fine, even after adding the id to a div. Are you using the same id to more than one dive?

Comment: yes I have about 30 divs with the same ID giving them their CSS

Comment: Don't have multiple elements with the same id, they are meant to be unique.

Comment: If so, how do I get the divs to have uniform CSS without conflicting the classes used for the function?

Comment: If multiple elements share the same styling, use classes.  Ids should be unique per page.  If you have multiple containers on a page, use a class "button-container".  It's fine to have unique ids, but never the same.  My main heading might have the id `#main-heading` but I won't have multiple instances.  If I did, I'd use a class and it wouldn't really be the "main" heading anymore would it?

Answer (score 1):

Ids have a priority of 100.
classes have a priority of 10.

So IDs will always have priority over classes, regardless of their location in the code.

The trick is to combine an ID and a class in your CSS, which gives a priority of 110:

```
#othercss_unrelated_to_function.filterDiv {...}
```

Comment: would making my ID a second class for the div help? I think if I take your advice there would be a lot of conflicting parameters. Please let me know if I am wrong about that !